# Image Processing in NVIDIA CUDA GPU

Tags: image-processing, gpu, ocr, nvidia

Is it possible that Image Processing can be implemented NVIDIA CUDA GPU? My Thesis proposal is .. i'm going to create an Optical Character Recognition which is being implemented in NVIDIA GPU. Is there anyone has an idea about this ? Is it really possible ? Do i have to pursue it ?

Comment: You probably want to read about this: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=gpgpu+image+processing&oq=gpgpu+image&gs_l=hp.3.0.0j0i22i30l3.777.3958.0.4966.12.12.0.0.0.0.128.958.10j2.12.0....0...1c.1.54.hp..1.11.870.0.NfVthUi6Avo

Comment: For example: http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/Staff/bgoldlue/cuda_ss_2012.php

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud - Yes it is.  I wrote various image filtering functions using CUDA... actually, I wrote it in Python with PyCUDA, but the kernel functions I wrote myself with CUDA.  This was a great reference: http://www.nvidia.com/content/nvision2008/tech_presentations/Game_Developer_Track/NVISION08-Image_Processing_and_Video_with_CUDA.pdf

Answer (score 0):

According to my good friend who works for Nvidia on CUDA: "It is possible and people use it already."

Comment: Do you know of any commercially available solutions based on this technology?